# providedIn: 'root' Vs NGRX?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Months ago I made this service for running loading spinner by injecting the service in `'root'` so I can use it everywhere in my application, nowadays I'm learning NGRX and I figured out that I can do the same purpose using state management on my app to run and stop the spinner,

my question is for best practice and better performance what is the better way to do it ?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingUtilsService {
  $loading: Subject<SpinnerLoading> = new Subject<SpinnerLoading>();
  constructor() { }
  startLoad(id) {
    this.$loading.next({ id: id, status: true });
  }
  stopLoad(id) {
    this.$loading.next({ id: id, status: false });
  }
}

export interface SpinnerLoading {
  id: string;
  status: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Only my opinion : I tried both, then spent 3 months removing all NGRX related code. imho, NGRX is a library developed by people coming from React and wanted React-style state management in Angular. But in Angular, sharing information can already be done with services provided in root + Subjects. Using NGRX ended in spaghetti code in my project

Comment: Also, you don't "have to" provide in root. In my current project, there is one "context service" for each feature module + one "root context service", depending at which level you want to share the information. The feature context services are injected at module level, only the root context service is `providedIn: root`

Comment: Both are pretty much the same, either one service with its own state, or a big one with all states... That's not gonna change much is it? From my point of view, it all depends on how you wanna do it. If there will be multiple states like 'onGoingXhr', 'waitingForInput' etc, and then you'd want your spinner to show on different states, I might see the point. But if it's just to act on "loading" state, that's not much to me.

Anyways, that global loading thing I got rid of ages ago, I prefer adding the loading in the component that needs it , what happens if you need 2 spinners?